# in display:flex, how can i specify the width of my element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

please take a look at this:

https://codepen.io/sir-j/pen/dyRVrPb

the problem i am facing is that although i set the `input [type=range]` to 500px, there is no difference from 100px, 500px or 800px, which makes me think that `display: flex` is messing with my elements, and giving it a maximum length. i want the width of `input [type=range]` to be the same as the height of its parent, in pixels. is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you need to ignore all max/min/auto widths set by flexbox, you can set `flex: 0 0 500px`, which is shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis.

Comment: Side note: `writing-mode: bt-lr; -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;` along with `orient='vertical'` attribute is easier to handle than transforms for vertical range sliders https://codepen.io/rod911/pen/BaZwbxm

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex grow, flex shrink or flex-basis, or you can simply use flex and give these details.